# Remap hotkeys per app but allow hold and release

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to remap some button on a bluetooth remote for use with a few art programs. I have a working script which works with Photoshop etc but I want to vary the key for Artrage and I believe I have succeeded in this. However, I also want to be able to hold and release the key (rather than have it press and immediately release.

Here is my code:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
#Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

#InstallKeybdHook

SetTimer, WatchWin, 2000 ;Checks the window every 2 seconds

WatchWin:
WinGetActiveTitle, ActiveTitle
If ActiveTitle Contains Photoshop, CameraRaw_WindowClass, CLIP STUDIO PAINT, ArtRage
{
    Volume_Up::]
    Volume_Down::[
    Media_Prev::^z
    Media_Next::^+z
    Media_Play_Pause::
    If ActiveTitle Contains ArtRage
        Send, +c
    Else
        Send, i
    Return
    ;Browser_Home::Space
    ;Volume_Mute::Space
}
Return
```

If I leave `Media_Play_Pause` defined as `Media_Play_Pause::i`, Windows treats this as held down until I release the button but when it has the If statement in place (as in the code block (above) is seems to press and immediately release.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Try `Media_Play_Pause Up::`

Answer (score 0):

This implements your script using [context-sensitive hotkeys](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm) and avoids using `send`:

```
SetTitleMatchMode 2     ; All #If statements match anywhere in title

#IfWinActive Photoshop
#IfWinActive CameraRaw_WindowClass
#IfWinActive CLIP STUDIO PAINT
  Volume_Up::]
  Volume_Down::[
  Media_Prev::^z
  Media_Next::^+z
  Media_Play_Pause::i
#IfWinActive ArtRage
  Volume_Up::]
  Volume_Down::[
  Media_Prev::^z
  Media_Next::^+z
  Media_Play_Pause::+c
#IfWinActive
```